# Binding Checkboxes to Specific Table Entries in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a small table of items that will not be changed. For each item entry in the table, there is a yes/no value that I want to bind to a checkbox in a form. The problem is, it seems like I can just bind to the column, not to specific entries in the table. How do I bind a checkbox to each item in the table?

I'm using Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your form using the 'Continuous Forms' option in the Form's format default view. You will see each record in the table with individual controls for each field.